# Json feeding dataTable through ajax call

Tags: json, datatables

I have a simple testing script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#dataTables-example').DataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": "../server/studentsdata.php"
        } );
    } );
</script>
```

This is my json response:

```
{"draw":0,"recordsTotal":57,"recordsFiltered":57,"data":[["Tiger Nixon","320800","61"],["Garrett Winters","170750","63"],["Ashton Cox","86000","66"],["Cedric Kelly","433060","22"],["Airi Satou","162700","33"],["Brielle Williamson","372000","61"],["Herrod Chandler","137500","59"],["Rhona Davidson","327900","55"],["Colleen Hurst","205500","39"],["Sonya Frost","103600","23"],["Jena Gaines","90560","30"],["Quinn Flynn","342000","22"],["Charde Marshall","470600","36"],["Haley Kennedy","313500","43"],["Tatyana Fitzpatrick","385750","19"],["Michael Silva","198500","66"],["Paul Byrd","725000","64"],["Gloria Little","237500","59"],["Bradley Greer","132000","41"],["Dai Rios","217500","35"],["Jenette Caldwell","345000","30"],["Yuri Berry","675000","40"],["Caesar Vance","106450","21"],["Doris Wilder","85600","23"],["Angelica Ramos","1200000","47"],["Gavin Joyce","92575","42"],["Jennifer Chang","357650","28"],["Brenden Wagner","206850","28"],["Fiona Green","850000","48"],["Shou Itou","163000","20"],["Michelle House","95400","37"],["Suki Burks","114500","53"],["Prescott Bartlett","145000","27"],["Gavin Cortez","235500","22"],["Martena Mccray","324050","46"],["Unity Butler","85675","47"],["Howard Hatfield","164500","51"],["Hope Fuentes","109850","41"],["Vivian Harrell","452500","62"],["Timothy Mooney","136200","37"],["Jackson Bradshaw","645750","65"],["Olivia Liang","234500","64"],["Bruno Nash","163500","38"],["Sakura Yamamoto","139575","37"],["Thor Walton","98540","61"],["Finn Camacho","87500","47"],["Serge Baldwin","138575","64"],["Zenaida Frank","125250","63"],["Zorita Serrano","115000","56"],["Jennifer Acosta","75650","43"],["Cara Stevens","145600","46"],["Hermione Butler","356250","47"],["Lael Greer","103500","21"],["Jonas Alexander","86500","30"],["Shad Decker","183000","51"],["Michael Bruce","183000","29"],["Donna Snider","112000","27"]]}
```

But I keep receiving this error:

> DataTables warning: table id=dataTables-example - Invalid JSON
>   response. For more information about this error, please see
>   http://datatables.net/tn/1

I tried to validate my json response on a few websites, and they all show it as valid.  Why is Datatables rejecting it?

**A update:**

If I paste my json response directly on the php page, it works. Look like the json is right, but for some reason the script is not sending correctly. When I try to access the script directed (by accessing the .php page), I get the correct json.

Comment: Seems a valid JSON but probably it is not valid for DataTable

Comment: Your data is not in valid `json` format

Comment: Parameter `draw` in your response is `0` however you should return the same value of `draw` from the request, which usually starts from 1 and increments with every request.

Comment: The reason the draw is 0, is because im calling the script directly, not through the page with the datatable content. Whenever I try to call regularly, there is no way I can see the ajax response, I even tried to open developer menu and resources, and haven't find anything.

Answer (score -1):

**Update!:**
Maybe its because of extra properties you are passing into `dataTable`!

try to change php part to produce something like this :

```
{
 "data":[
    ["name":"Tiger Nixon","value":"320800","age":"61"],
    ["name":"Garrett Winters","value":"170750","age":"63"]
    .
    .
    .
 ]
}
```

Comment: You technically have to pass the other proprieties. I tried to remove them, but still got the same error.